# Is there a way to associate input as the name of a list?

Tags: python

I want the name of a list to be raw_input, how do I do that in python 2.7?

Comment: Suppose you did this. How would you refer to it in your code?

Comment: a `list` object does not have a name

Answer (score 5):

Something is already horribly wrong.

```
# This is a horrible monstrosity, but it does what you ask
name = raw_input('name> ')
globals()[name] = [1, 2, 3]
```

You should be using a proper dictionary instead.

```
x = { }
name = raw_input('name> ')
x[name] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Lists don't actually have names.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
```

What is the name of `[1, 2, 3]`?  Wrong question, it doesn't have a name, it only has a value (and a location in memory).  Only variables have names.